# Fuse.js's example code doesn't return any result

Tags: fuse.js

Here is the example code of [Fuse.js](https://www.fusejs.io/):

```js
import Fuse from "https://deno.land/x/fuse/dist/fuse.esm.js";

const list = [
    {
      "title": "Old Man's War",
      "author": "John Scalzi",
      "tags": ["fiction"]
    },
    {
      "title": "The Lock Artist",
      "author": "Steve",
      "tags": ["thriller"]
    }
]

const options = {
    includeScore: true
}

const fuse = new Fuse(list, options)
const result = fuse.search('od man')

console.log(" ~ fuse:", fuse)
console.log(" ~ result:", result)
```

The result is just `[]`. Do you know why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not configured the keys:

```js
const options = {
  includeScore: true,
  keys: ['title', 'author'],
};
```

will give you result:

```json
[
  {
    item: { title: "Old Man's War", author: 'John Scalzi', tags: [Array] },
    refIndex: 0,
    score: 0.3556368284111493
  }
]
```

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. I read the [Options](https://www.fusejs.io/api/options.html#keys "Options | Fuse.js") and see that the default value of keys is `[]`. So I though leaving it as and empty array or even remove it was fine. Why isn't that the case? And how to search for all keys?

Comment: It seems that fuse doesn't support search over all keys. At lest, they have corresponding issue reported: https://github.com/krisk/Fuse/issues/110